# Updating a vector layer while zooming, instead of after zooming in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

See the problem here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqIieehQoPc

I want OpenLayers to draw all the lines and labels seen at the end of the video, but *while* the zoom is in progress. Is there an easy configuration I can pass? Or is the only solution here a costly deep dive into OpenLayers' internals?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set updateWhileAnimating and updateWhileInteracting to true in your layer setup for each layer you want to render while the map is being interacted with/animated.

See the parameter options at: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_VectorTile-VectorTileLayer.html